# Restore Local Users which got deleted while demoting the domain controller

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

All my local users on the SharePoint server got deleted while demoting the domain controller.

I'm new to the SharePoint. Without much research, I installed an Active Directory on my SharePoint server. After that it asked me to "Promote the server to the domain controller" and I did this. All my local users came under the domain and also my SharePoint site stopped working.

After that to make the SharePoint site work I demoted the domain controller, but in this process, all the local users got deleted. After this, I cannot connect to the SQL Server, neither SharePoint Central Administrator is working and the site is also not working.

I want to know whether I can restore the deleted users, and put things back to where it was and bring the site online.

I got this thread for reference, but I'm not sure whether it is going to work. Even I don't want to spoil things even more.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/840001/how-to-restore-deleted-user-accounts-and-their-group-memberships-in-ac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint Server does not support local accounts -- they need to be domain accounts, so it sounds like now is a great time to switch.

Without a system state backup, you cannot restore *local* users.